# Vacation in Dubai, then Seychelles, returning through Dubai. Will I need more than 1 visa (to Dubai)?

Tags: visas, dubai, south-african-citizens

As a South-African citizen, I have received a valid 30-day tourist visa for Dubai, UAE. At the end of my vacation, I will be traveling on to the Seychelles for a few days, before returning home. My return flight has me arriving in Dubai with a one night layover before my final flight the next day back to South-Africa.

Do I need to get a second visa for the one night I'll be spending in Dubai on the return flight's layover?

Comment: I'm not familiar with UAE visas but does your visa (e-visa?) say it is single entry or multiple entry?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, its a transit & you don't need any visa at all for your return flight.
Also, if your return stay is longer than 12 hours, the airline would provide you with a transit visa of 24 hours. (if you're traveling with Emirates. I'm not sure about other airlines).